# How can I copy certain file types in multiple subfolders and paste them in an empty folder while keeping the file structure of the original folders?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, directory, windows-10, directory-structure

I am trying to copy music lyric files (.lrc) from a folder with many subfolders such as artists and albums and paste them in an empty folder, but I still want to keep the folder structure without having to create each individual folder for those files to be put in. In other words: I want to take certain files from a folder and have it automatically create the folder structure in another folder which the original file was in.

For example: I have 10 lyric files accompanied with other music files in a single folder called "ArtistName" which is a subfolder of a subfolder of a folder called "Music". These lyric files need to be in another folder called "Music2" that is currently empty, but instead of just dumping the files in the root folder, I need to recreate the folder structure in which the original lyric files were in.

Is there any way to do this? Keep in mind, I am not very experienced when it comes to programming but I know some basics. Unfortunately I might need more of an explanation than most people here. Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: Who knows. Type `xcopy /?`.

Comment: Check out ‘robocopy’.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a powershell answer:

Use Copy-Item with the *-Container* and *-Recurse* switches to copy the folder structure including files to a new location.

```
Copy-Item -Path "Old\Path\for\Music" -Recurse -Destination "New\Path\for\Music" -Container
```

If you only want to copy the lyric files while retaining the folder structure use a *-Filter*

```
Copy-Item -Path "Old\Path\for\Music" -Recurse -Filter "*.lrc" -Destination "New\Path\for\Music" -Container
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CMD

```
xcopy /s yourFolder\Subfolder\*.pdf destinationFolder\myfolder
```

---

powershell, recurse option keeps the folder structure

```
copy-item c:\\srcFolders\\* f:\\dst -force -recurse -verbose
```